# How to combine the $_SESSION into one variable in PHP mysqli ?

Tags: php, arrays

normally, i use the **single $_SESSION** for single field in the table as below in mysqli, let's say i use **'email'** field in **users** table

```
$email              = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST["email"]);
$_SESSION['email']  =$email;
```

but it only can use email as sessions right ?

But what if i have multiple fields in the **users** table such as **username, password, gender** ?. How to combine/bind all the $_SESSION fields together into one variable ?

```
$user = $sessions_variable['username'];
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: create a variable with data type array. Store that variable inside your session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_SESSON is an *array*. So your first move is to [read up on arrays in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

After that you'll be able to either assign different values to different $_SESSON elements

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

or, after getting the user info from a database, assign it to a single element

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multidimensional array in session like this

```
$_SESSION['user']['username']  =$username;
$_SESSION['user']['email']  =$email;
```

then you can pass whole user session array to single variable.

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create multidimensional array for session follow the below procedure. 
Example:

```
$_SESSION['foo']['foo_1']  =$foo1;
$_SESSION['foo']['foo_2']  =$foo2;
$_SESSION['foo']['foo_3']  =$foo3;
...
```

Now if we want to use whole foo array in single variable. you have to pass it like this.

```
$foo_whole_session = $_SESSION['foo'];
```

You can check what you found using `print_r($_SESSION)`.